# Working with domain services

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-services

I created a domain service on the server side. Build the project. But I still don't have the domain proxy at the client side for the created service. Should I add any new namespaces to the client project? I tried Add Service on the client project, but there is no newly created domain service in the list (I pressed Discover button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter. If I understand your question exactly, these can be the right answer:

- After clicking "Show All Files" button in your Solution Explorer, You can find the client proxy of domain services at the hidden Generated_Code folder.

  The *.Web.g.cs code may be generated by reflection of server side compiled assembly.
- So,you can use the proxy by just adding namespace after building solution.

For example,

```
using myApp.Web.Models;
using myApp.Web.Services;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;

namespace myApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
    MyModelContext _context = new MyModelContext(); 
    }
...
}
```

Comment: @peter If you are exploring Silverlight + RIA, I recommend this good articles from here [link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx).